# Google play service make app crash

Tags: android, google-play-services

Here is my `gradle`:

```
 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'

 compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'

 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'

 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
```

When I remove  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'` , app *works fine*, but when put it in, *app crashes*:

Here is `logcat`:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:77)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:414)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:57)
            at com.laseek.pepe.activity.ActivitySplash.onCreate(ActivitySplash.java:21)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2244)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5092)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Android Support Library and Android Support Repository. Just install using the SDK manager. They are not synced with each other. Make sure you have them according to your SDK.

Via the SDK Manager, you need to make sure you have `Android Support Repository` up to date

Answer (score 0):

If you use Android Studio and want to use the latest Google libraries via Gradle dependency, you will have to update the

You can do this via Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> You have to update the stuff under Extras

Check whether you have `google-play-services` installed.[image: google-play-services]

If not please install them and try syncing the `gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

I try to install app on my Nexus 5, it works fine, but on other phone with android under version 5.0 it didn't work